# BadPtr Access Violation in loop-while to convert char** into std::vector<string>

Tags: c++, string, exc-bad-access, stdvector

I have a access violation problem in these folowing loop.
My problem: I can't know the number of `char*` into `char**` params. So I can't do something like

```
for (int i=0; i<size; i++){...}
```

My code is the following:

```
void vecCharPtr2StrVec(const char** params, std::vector<string> &s_paramVec){

int idx = 0;
const char *name = params[idx++];

string s_name;
while(name != NULL){
    s_name = string(name);
    s_paramVec.push_back(s_name);
    name = params[idx++];
} }
```

It populates the `s_paramVec` but access a bad location at `0xcccccccc` after the last `s_name` be pushed back.

How can I do the stop condition?

Thank you a lot.

Comment: You have to have some way of knowing how big the array is; either a NULL terminator or pass the number of elements in as a separate parameter.

Comment: No, I don't. The best way to do it that I found was the second solution published by juhist below: using sizeof. Thanks a lot.

Comment: the "second solution" was exactly what I suggested - passing the size of the array to the function.

Comment: The second solution used `sizeof` to discover how big the array is, just as suggested by @JonathanPotter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code implicitly assumes that there is a `NULL` terminator. It seems you're not having it in the array.

Try this:

```
std::vector<string> v;
const char *params[] = {"a", "b", "c", NULL};
vecCharPtr2StrVec(params, v);
std::cout << v[2] << std::endl;
```

Another option would be to pass the length of params:

```
std::vector<string> v;
const char *params[] = {"a", "b", "c"};
vecCharPtr2StrVec(params, sizeof(params)/sizeof(params[0]), v);
std::cout << v[2] << std::endl;
```

...but that would require changes to `vecCharPtr2StrVec` to honor the passed length.